# How to use "-b" with celery

Tags: celery

everyone.

I have a problem with celery's parameter "-b", i found it in the celery document:

> -b, --broker
>
> celery command line option

but it seems doesn't take effect when I use like this, example:

`celery -A tasks worker -b redis://yuhui:mypassword@192.168.1.100/0 --loglevel=INFO`

tasks.py

```py
from celery import Celery
    
app = Celery('tasks')
    
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

The command line logs like blow:

```
 -------------- celery@yuhui v4.4.2 (cliffs)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.3.0-46-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid 2020-04-19 11:45:00
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x7f903f18cdd0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://yuhui:**@192.168.1.100:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

But, it will stuck without any return when I execute `celery -A tasks inspect active`.

If I change this line

```py
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://yuhui:mypassword@192.168.1.100/0')
```

It will be fine.

BTW, I don't have a redis on my current machine.

So, how to use this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass broker param to inspect command

```
celery -A tasks inspect -b redis://yuhui:mypassword@192.168.1.100/0 active
```